# Experiencing Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method in Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macros. Infact this is my first macro. I am trying to execute this macro. I am facing a run time error.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScaleAxes()
  With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("I17").Value
    .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("I18").Value
    .MajorUnit = ActiveSheet.Range("I19").Value
  End With
End Sub
```

Basically my task is , i am trying to change the x Axies value of a Line chart dynamically based on my table's max and min value. So i have calculated max and min value from my table using min and max function and passing those values through I17:I19. Not sure how much i am correct.

Comment: I17 , I18 and I19 are minimum x axies vale , maximum x axies value

Comment: Which line are you receiving the error on?

Comment: Do you have values in I17, I18 and I19? I mean, are you sure they aren't empty?

Comment: No line is mentioned. And as i am new to VBA i am not able to judge the same. But recently on goggling i found that i my sheet codename which i had specified was wrong i changed it and ran again. But now i get another error. "Method MinimumScale of object Axies failed". Basically i am the task i am trying to perform is to change the x Axies value dynamically based on my table's max and min value. So i have calculated max and min value from my table using min and max function and passing those values through I17:I19. Not sure how much i am correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem you are having is due to the fact that you are trying to set the Minimum and Maximum values on a Category axis which does not support them. If you changed **xlCategory** to **xlValue** then it should work (on a chart that has a value axis not a category axis).

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScaleAxes()
  With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
    .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("I17").Value
    .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("I18").Value
    .MajorUnit = ActiveSheet.Range("I19").Value
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you. Thats just the perfect answer.